# CSS / Drupal - Contact form collapses on itself

Tags: css, responsive-design, drupal-7, contact-form

I am using a contact form for Drupal with 2 blocks, on the left is for Google Maps and on the right is the form.

This works fine when it's full screen, however when reducing the browser window for responsiveness the form field on the right collapses on the Google maps block.

Full screen is fine

[image]

Collapsing on itself with the browser width reduced
[image]

I've tried using `max-width: 100%` but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I change the CSS so that the form code goes to the bottom of the Google Maps block instead of stacking on top of each other?

**CSS**

Google Maps code

```
.page-contact .block-google-maps {
margin-right: 2%;
min-height: 500px;
float:left;
max-width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

Form code

```
position: absolute;
right: 100px;
top: 110px;
width: 40%;
```

Comment: The reason the contact form overlaps the map is because you are `position: absolute`ing the form. So it will always appear on the right of the page. You must use CSS breakpoints to move each block on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS is looks like hard-coded, for perfect responsiveness use @media rules in CSS for different screen sizes.
One more suggestion is: In small screens keep the two items(Google map and contact form) vertically instead of horizontal.